# Duvida no Linql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tenho 2 tabelas: uma de produto e outra com uma lista de conversão. 
Teria como eu fazer uma unica conexão com o banco de dados sem ter que ir varias vezes no banco?
Por exemplo, a cada produto tenho uma lista de conversão, na  lista de consulta pego os produtos e a lista de conversão.

**Código**

```
        public List<DTO.Produtos> ListarProdutos()
    {
        var listarProduto = new List<DTO.Produtos>();

        using (var context = new DbContextEmpilhadeiras())
        {
            var lista = context.TB_Produtos.OrderBy(p => p.Descricao).ToList();



            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                DTO.Produtos objProduto = new DTO.Produtos
                {
                    IDProduto = item.ID_Produto,
                    Descricao = item.Descricao,
                    CodigoInterno = item.CodigoInterno,
                    Localizacao = item.Localizacao,
                    QtdAtualFisico = item.EstoqueAtual.ToString(),
                    TodosCodigosConversao = item.Conversao,
                };


                var listaConversao = context.TB_ProdutoConversao.Where(c => c.IDProduto == item.ID_Produto && c.DtExclusao == null).ToList();
                if (listaConversao != null)
                {
                    foreach (var itemC in listaConversao)
                    {
                        objProduto.TodosCodigosConversao += (itemC.Codigo + " ** ");
                    }
                }



                listarProduto.Add(objProduto);
            }
        }

        return listarProduto;
    }
```

tentei fazer desta forma mais a lista da conversão veio vazia

```
            var lista = (from p in context.TB_Produtos
                         join io in context.TB_ProdutoConversao on p.ID_Produto equals io.IDProduto
                         select p).OrderBy(p => p.Descricao).ToList();
```

eu queria ir uma unida vez no banco e pegar todas as listas de conversão que pertence ao produto  e não a  cada foreach porque a aplicação ficou lenta

obrigado

Comment: Pode nos mostrar como está a modelagem do seu banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou realizar essa consulta com SQL? Se você consegue fazer ela com SQL você certamente consegue fazer com Linq também.
Outro ponto é usar o relacionamento da tabela pelo entity framework.

Comment: eu não sei como fazer este relacionamento